# Could not instantiate Google Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to instantiate Google Calendar:

```
Calendar service = new Calendar(httpTransport, jsonFactory, accessProtectedResource);
```

but I get an error

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

I am getting `accessProtectedResource`:

```
GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                "access token", httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
                "refresh token");
```

tokens I get from OAuth 2 Playground.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct `com.google.api.client.util.Strings` class in your classpath when executing the code.

Comment: I added all dependensies in pom.xml, including client.util which includes Strings

Comment: And is it in the right version? I mean, the included package contains the `Strings` class with the right method?

Comment: I changed all my dependensies to lastest version. and no changes